# Sql query to create a calculated field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, qsqlquery

I have a database table like this:
[image]
I hope I can explain this well, so you can understand.

I want to calculate how many hours each employee has worked.
For example for "Arjeta Domi" we have Cell(2,3) - Cell(3,3) + Cell(4,3) + Cell(5,3), making the difference of each logOut time with Login time.

[image]

The final table that I want will have these columns: `CardNo`, `UserName`, `Date`, `PauseTime`, `WorkTime`

I tried this query: taken from the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929155/sql-query-with-inner-select)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [Card NO], 
  [User Name],  
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(DateTime) AS [Enter Time], 
      MAX(DateTime) AS [Exit Time], 
      MAX(DateTime) - MIN(DateTime) AS [Inside Hours] 
    FROM
      ExcelData
  ) 
FROM
  ExcelData
GROUP BY
  [Card NO], [User Name], DateTime
```

The `DateTime` Column is of type `String`, not `DateTime`.
I am working with MS Access Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all rows with 'm001-1-In' with DateTime as I and add the fitting 'm001-1-Exit' rows to this with a Subquery as O, this will look like this:

```
SELECT t1.[Card No], t1.[User Name],dateTime as I
,(Select TOP 1 dateTime from Tab t2 where  t2.[Card No]= t1.[Card No] 
and  t2.[User Name]= t1.[User Name] and  t2.Addr='m001-1-Exit' 
and t2.DateTime>t1.datetime ORDER by DateTime) as O
FROM Tab t1
where t1.Addr='m001-1-In'
```

[image]

Now it's easy to encapsulate this, show as Prepared below and add our SUM and Grouping to this:

```
SELECT [Prepared].[Card No], [Prepared].[User Name], SUM(DateDiff('n',I,O))/60 AS Hours
FROM (
      SELECT t1.[Card No], t1.[User Name],dateTime as I
    ,(Select TOP 1 dateTime from Tab t2 where  t2.[Card No]= t1.[Card No] 
      and  t2.[User Name]= t1.[User Name] and  t2.Addr='m001-1-Exit' 
      and t2.DateTime>t1.datetime ORDER by DateTime) as O
FROM Tab t1
where t1.Addr='m001-1-In' 
)  AS [Prepared]
GROUP BY [Prepared].[Card No], [Prepared].[User Name]
```

If you need to restrict the DateRange you add the needed conditions to the row `where t1.Addr='m001-1-In'`

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask you if is it possible to use this query to make an insert. ex: INSERT INTO fTable(f1,f2,f3) SELECT g1,h2,g3 FROM "yourQuery"  Inner Join hTable in [here the fields]?
It would be very helpful, Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, but something like `Insert into dest (f1,f2,f3)
Select a.[Card No],x.SomeField, a.Hours from
(
<myquery>
) a
Inner JOIN Tabx x ON x.f1=a.[Card No] AND .......` will work

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Ok, I will test if it. Thank you!

Comment: Ok looks good. I have one last request. One of the values I want to insert is a variable. Ex. INSERT INTO DEST(f1,f2,f3) SELECT variable, x.SomeField, a.Hours FROM (<query>) A Inner Join Tabx x On x.id = a.[cardNo]. I guess the variable cannot be inserted like this from "From (<query>)..."!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CardNo, UserName, SUM(DATEDIFF('h',DateTime,(SELECT MIN(Datetime) 
                                                    FROM table as t2 
                                                    WHERE t1.CardNo=t2.CardNo
                                                        AND t2.Addr like '%Exit' 
                                                        AND t2.DateTime > t1.DateTime )))
FROM table as t1
WHERE Addr like '%In'
GROUP BY CardNo, UserName
```