# Sql Query with inner select

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [Card NO], 
  [User Name],  
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(DateTime) AS [Enter Time], 
      MAX(DateTime) AS [Exit Time], 
      MAX(DateTime) - MIN(DateTime) AS [Inside Hours] 
    FROM
      ExcelData
  ) 
FROM
  ExcelData
GROUP BY
  [Card NO], [User Name], DateTime
```

Table Schema: `CardNO | UserName | DateTime`

I tried to execute it but with no success. I says that it is an invalid query.
Can anyone find what is wrong in this query?

Comment: Is it MySQL, SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: `MySQL`, `SQL Server` and `MS Access` are not the same.. Which one do you really use? Based on the identifier delimiters (`[` and `]`)  this is SQL Server

Comment: MS Access would be better

Comment: The question looks like your last question? [Sql query to create a calculated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915156/sql-query-to-create-a-calculated-field)

Comment: Yes it is the same, but I didn't get an answer so I asked again, and changed a little the question

Comment: Don't do that, you might always improve a question you made. Duplicates will be closed.

Comment: I thought it wan't show in the recent questions any more and no one will answer anymore.

Comment: What is the type of column `DateTime`?

Comment: It show Date Time Day(in string) ex: 10/10/2014 00:00:00 Friday

Comment: So the column type of `DateTime` is `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Yes, it is VARCHAR, sorry I didn't see it

Comment: @eviB - if you edit a question it gets bumped to the head of the home page again and is treated like a a recent question.

Answer (score 0):

This would not resolve your possible Problems with reserved keywords and column names, but should be a valid query. You were using a select query as column Name.

```
SELECT
    [Card NO], 
    [User Name], 
    MIN(DateTime) AS [Enter Time], 
    MAX(DateTime) AS [Exit Time], 
    MAX(DateTime) - MIN(DateTime) AS [Inside Hours] 
  FROM
    ExcelData
  GROUP BY
     [Card NO], [User Name]
```

Comment: I don't think it has any conflict with reserved words because when I execute:    SELECT DateTime From ExcelData, it show the DateTime Column. But also when I executed your query it doesn't work.

Comment: try to remove the distinct keyword. And what is your error message?

Comment: Now it was executed but with no results. Empty table

Comment: My original table looks like this : http://s15.postimg.org/lvrb3102j/table.png

Comment: I do not know whether [Card NO] is the right Syntax. Does 'SELECT[Card NO] FROM ExcelData' works?

Comment: Yes it is right syntax "Card NO" is the column name

Comment: I changed the DateTime column name to TheDate and still doesn't work. DateTime is of Type : ex "02/01/2015 00:00:00 Friday"

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by DateTime, which is a reserved keyword, and you don't select a column DateTime. You do select aggregates over DateTime, which means you shouldn't group on it. @irene got the right answer.