# Associating Records Together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data stored within a table.

```
DateCreated              ServerName  Heading

2014-09-23 13:43:31.477 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 13:30:23.017 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 13:26:21.110 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 13:20:42.243 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 13:16:30.457 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 13:15:03.993 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 13:08:36.763 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 13:05:59.490 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 12:59:30.017 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 12:55:49.303 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 09:54:43.180 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 09:52:05.453 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 09:46:55.013 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 09:44:54.957 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 09:11:24.100 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 09:06:55.703 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 08:59:53.773 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect

2014-09-23 07:55:35.537 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server running

2014-09-23 07:49:50.830 LAB1\TEST   SQL Server status: Unable To Connect
```

I'm needing to associate all of the "Unable to Connect" records with the appropriate "SQL Server running" record and figure out the duration between each one.

It needs to take into account that there may not be a "SQL Server running" record as per the above example at "2014-09-23 13:43:31.477" which means it is still down.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could approach this?

Comment: Select the `unable to connect` left Join the `running` and get a DateDiff for the 2 `DateCreated` columns with IsNull(DateCreated,GetDate()).

Comment: This question is where close to yours [Sql query to create a calculated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915156/sql-query-to-create-a-calculated-field), NOT a duplicate since it's access and with SQLServer you might find a CTE solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all connection failure records. For each show the next (i.e. smallest later) connection time.

```
select 
  datecreated, 
  servername,
  (
    select min(running.datecreated)
    from mytable running
    where running.heading = 'SQL Server running'
    and running.servername = notrunning.servername
    and running.datecreated > notrunning.datecreated
  ) as connected
from mytable notrunning
where heading = 'SQL Server status: Unable To Connect';
```

Based on this you can calculate the duration. Be aware that you may get several failed tries for one connection. You may consider to only show the first failure for each connection and ignore the additional ones. That would take a more complicated query though. (Or does your table store only the first failure anyhow? Then you already got what's needed.)

Comment: Thanks for that, that's perfect. :) Yes you're right with your statement. I'm just getting back the the first unable to connect record and using that as the starting point. It's easy enough to do that because its just a "Status".